# Using NPM Module in regular javascript file

Tags: javascript, npm

I am trying to use the NPM Module React-Geocode in a regular javascript file, not a react component file. Can anyone tell me why this won't work?

Long story short - I have re-written my website previously made with plugins in wordpress... One of the things that users do is type their city into to their profile so they can be searched by location. I used React-Geocode in my react website to accomplish this. It turns their entered city into coordinates.

I am done coding and want to import my old users to the new website... so I wrote the file below to take my list of users from the old site and put them on the new site. The problem is.. the coordinates wouldn't export from wordpress.

Any ideas why this wont work? It says "Geocode.setApiKey(....) is not a function."

```
    const uuidv4 = require('uuid')
const BulkBands = require('./BulkBands')
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const Geocode = require('react-geocode')

let bandCount = 0

Geocode.setApiKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

const addTheBand = async (newBand, band) => {

    let newLocation = []

    Geocode.fromAddress(band.bandLocation).then(
        response => {
        const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
        console.log(lat, lng);
        newLocation = [ lng, lat ]
        },
        error => {
        console.error(error);
        }
    );

    try {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/autoquotegenerators', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(newBand)
            })
            const responseData = await response.json()
            if(responseData){
                console.log('Band Added');
                setTimeout(() => {
                    updateBandLocation({
                        geometry: {
                            coordinates: newLocation,
                            city: band.bandLocation,
                        }
                    }, responseData._id, responseData, band)
                }, 500)
            }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

}

const updateBandLocation = async (newLocation, bandUserId, band, oldBand) => {
    console.log('adding location...')

    let newPosts = [...band.posts]

    if(oldBand.youtube1){
        newPosts.push({
            type: "video", 
            data: oldBand.youtube1, 
            date: new Date(), 
            postId: uuidv4(), 
            rockOn: []
        })
    }

    if(oldBand.youtube2){
        newPosts.push({
            type: "video", 
            data: oldBand.youtube2, 
            date: new Date(), 
            postId: uuidv4(), 
            rockOn: []
        })
    }

try {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/autoquotegenerators/${bandUserId}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            bandLocation: newLocation,
            posts: newPosts
        })
    })
    const responseData = await response.json()

    bandCount += 1

    console.log(bandCount)

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
}


BulkBands.forEach(band => {

    addTheBand({
        quoteGenerator: [],
        userId: band.userId,
        posts: [
            {
                "type": "band",
                "data": "",
                "date": new Date(),
                "postId": uuidv4(),
                "approved": null,
                "rockOn": []
            },
        ],
        type: 'band',
        bandName: band.bandName,
        bandEmail: band.bandEmail,
        bandGenre: band.bandGenre,
        bandBio: band.bandBio,
        youtube: [band.youtube1, band.youtube2],
        published: false,
        cancellationPolicy: 'You may cancel this performance up to 2 weeks prior to the performance date without penalty. If this performance is cancelled within 2 weeks of the performance date the booking party will be required to pay 50% of the booking fee to the band. If the booking is cancelled within 3 days of the performance date the full payment is required to be paid to the band. ',
        baseCost: band.baseCost,
        mainDate: {
        charge: band.timedRate,
        sunday: 0,
        monday: 0,
        tuesday: 0,
        wednesday: 0,
        thursday: 0,
        friday: 0,
        saturday: 0,
    }
    }, band) 
})
```

Comment: Did you `npm install` all the packages?

Comment: Yes I see the "react-geocode": "^0.2.1", in my dependencies in the package.json file, I required it in the file above, and it still says that the Geocode.xxxx() is not a function. Is it just not possible to use the NPM package here?

Comment: Do you get any results when you `console.log(Geocode)`?